# FFMPEG : custom sequence input images

Tags: ffmpeg

I created a video from a set of images.

The command look like:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -i img_%d.png -filter_complex overlay=5:H-h-5[b]-shortest testvid.mp4
```

**Problem:**

The input `-i img_%d.png` means `img_0.png`, `img_1.png`, `img_2.png`, ...

But I have custom sequence like this: `{img_0.png, img_1.png, img_1.png, img_2.png, img_1.png, img5.png, img_4.png}`

**Question:**

Can I put my image sequence into input of ffmpeg?

**Updated**
cmd:

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -f concat -fflags +genpts -i test.txt -filter_complex overlay=5:H-h-5 -shortest testvid.mp4
```

output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libfreetype
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'bg.jpeg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 47329 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 600x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, concat, from 'test.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 200x200, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'testvid.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[swscaler @ 0x2a18360] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] 264 - core 148 r2705 3f5ed56 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[mp4 @ 0x2a04b20] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, mp4, to 'testvid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 600x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.48.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[concat @ 0x29e2400] DTS -230575710986777 < 0 out of order
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      39kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=8050.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=65 speed=0.516x    
video:39kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.222729%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] frame I:1     Avg QP:24.64  size: 37536
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] frame P:1     Avg QP:27.18  size:  1085
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] frame B:2     Avg QP:29.93  size:    73
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] consecutive B-frames: 25.0%  0.0% 75.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] mb I  I16..4:  1.7% 86.1% 12.2%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  1.7%  1.3%  1.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:95.5%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.4%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:97.6%  L0:62.6% L1:37.4% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] 8x8 transform intra:86.1% inter:33.9%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 91.5% 84.4% 38.5% inter: 0.6% 0.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] i16 v,h,dc,p:  9% 12%  3% 76%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 19% 17%  8%  4%  5%  5%  7% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 18% 10% 10%  9%  7% 10%  8%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 21% 26%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] ref B L0: 84.2% 15.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2a05d80] kb/s:1938.35
```

Comment: Why dont you copy these files into a temporary directory, and name them with the sequence you need? Like, `cp img_2.png img_3.png`, `cp img_1.png img_2.png`, etc?

Comment: I think about it, my sequence is about 100-200 files, it's not the best way. But if it is impossible for another, it is the only solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the concat demuxer with the custom sequence.

First, create a text file:

```
file 'img_0.png'
file 'img_1.png'
file 'img_1.png'
file 'img_2.png'
file 'img_1.png'
file 'img5.png'
file 'img_4.png'
```

Then run

```
ffmpeg -i bg.jpeg -f concat -r 25 -i list.txt -filter_complex "overlay=5:H-h-5" -shortest out.mp4
```

**Edit**: For PNG and most other image formats, `r` should be expressly specified to initialize a duration for each image entry in the list.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not work. My output [concat @ 0x349a400] DTS -230575710986777 < 0 out of order DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
PTS -230575710986777, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
DTS -230575710986777, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      39kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=8050.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=65 speed=0.45x    
video:39kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.222729%

Comment: Show full console output.

Comment: Can I write it to your email?

Comment: I added output log

Comment: I found the solution: Into list.txt needs to adding duration 0.01 after each line. file 'img_0.png'
duration 0.01
file 'img_1.png'
duration 0.01
file 'img_1.png'
duration 0.01

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with JPG sequence and getting no errors. Tried it with PNG and get errors. If you add `-r 25` before `-i list.txt`, you'll still get errors but the video will be well-formed.

Comment: upvoted for the last comment: For lists of PNG files, `-r <framerate>` is required to produce a video without errors

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue, and if you have the need to generate image list as a part of program execution, then consider adding a `duration <sec>` string after every `file <path>` line, which will make the filter infer DTS. Like below:

```
file 'img.00000020.png'
duration 0.03333
file 'img.00000021.png'
duration 0.03333
...
```

For the case of offline conversion of a bunch of images, inline globbing worked just fine (so yes - DTS errors come from concat filter), but the following bash command can provide a list for the dry run:

```
for i in img.*.png; do echo file \'$i\'; echo duration 0.03333; done > list.txt
```

Comment: a related question. if my images (.png) are coming through the standard input (stdin) as a stream then i cannot create a list file in advance. how do i handle this situation ? an example of this is stream_images.exe {args} | ffmpeg -y -vcodec png -i - -vf fps=25 -vcodec libx264 foo.mp4