# Making a movie out of pictures in correct order

Tags: video, ffmpeg, wildcard

**Short version**

How can one combine files `img1000.png`, `img5000.png`, `img10000.png`, `img11000.png` in the right order into a movie?

**Longer version**

I am using ffmpeg to make a movie out of snapshots of a simulation. There should be for instance 5 images per second. The names are:

```
image0200.png
image0300.png
image0400.png
image0500.png
image1000.png
image1500.png
image2000.png
...
image8500.png
image9000.png
image9500.png
image10000.png
image15000.png
```

i.e., they are sequential but there are irregular gaps in the numbers. The numbers are formatted according to  `'%04d'` but go above 9999. I have tried

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -nostats \
-r:v 5 -thread_queue_size 1024 -f image2 \
-pattern_type glob -i "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png" \
-r:v 30 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 28 \
-an  AMDG.mp4
```

and many, many other variations but either only two frames end up being visible in the movie (even though the images are found when using -debug) or only the files up to `image9500.png` are used (and `glob` does not seem to allow `[0-9]{4,}` as for regex), or, with

```
    ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -nostats \
    -r:v 5 \
    -thread_queue_size 1024 -f image2 -pattern_type glob \
       -i "image[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png" \
    -r:v 5 \
    -thread_queue_size 1024 -f image2 -pattern_type glob \
       -i "image[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].png" \
    -r:v 30 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 28 \
    -map 0 -map 1 \
    -an  AMDG.mp4
```

there are apparently two streams in the output movie and only one of them is being played. (I realised in the process `-map 0 -map 1` was needed in order for both input streams to be used.)

In one of the variations of options I found (now I have lost what it was exactly!) all images were included but the order was not the desired one: `image1000.png` was shown before `image10000.png`. Apparently a newer version of ffmpeg (I have `ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2`) has the ability to sort like `sort -V`, so that `image10000` come after `image1000`, but reinstalling ffmpeg is in general not a practical option. Also renaming the files is not practical and creating e.g. soft links with sequential names in the format '%05d' starting at 0 and in steps of 1 (so that `-i '%05d'` could be used) is of course not elegant.

With the `-concat` filter as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77016/ffmpeg-pattern-type-glob-not-loading-files-in-correct-order, i.e.,

```
  ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -nostats -r:v 5 \
    -thread_queue_size 1024 -f image2 -f concat \
    -safe 0 -i <(find . -maxdepth 1 -regex 'image*.png' \
       -exec echo "file $(pwd)/"{} \; | sort -V) \
    -r:v 30 -codec:v libx264 -preset veryslow -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 28 \
    -an \
    AMDG.mp4
```

the processing took a long time and made the whole system sluggish, while producing a movie of ~60 kB showing only two different images.

I have the impression that there are several issues at once... Thanks if you can help!

Comment: How about something like `ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -vcodec libx264 out.mp4` as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/666860/clarification-for-ffmpeg-input-option-with-image-files-as-input)? In case nothing works, consider using a Python script.

Comment: Thanks but `-pattern_type glob -i '*.png'` puts the files in the wrong order (`10000`, `1000`, `10500`, ..., `6000`, etc.) as listed with `-loglevel debug` and even with `-r:v 2` before `-i` and `-r:v 10` before `-vcodec` (to make it very slow) only two different images are visible in the movie for some irregular amount of time. I cannot use `-start_number` from that link because my numbers do not increase by 1. What would be the content of the script, whether in `bash`, `python`, etc.?

Comment: Using a Python script we can read the PNG file names into a list, and sort the list by the prefix number (sorting in Python is relatively simple). After having the list sorted, we can read each PNG file at a time, and write the content to stdin pipe of FFmpeg sub-process. (it's just a bit slower).

Comment: Eureka! Embarassingly, the issue was that while testing I overwrote most PNGs with one another so that different files had the same content---thus one problem was not with the movie. To get the right order (once the frames are different again...), indeed `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i List.txt ...` works, where `List.txt` can be made on the fly with the `... <(find ...)` part above (see "process substitution" under [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer). With `... | sort -V | tee list.txt)` you can save the list. No need for an external script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: With only the file names in List.txt (with "file " in front), I get a lot of
`[concat @ 0x556604e50940] DTS -230584300921369 < 0 out of order`
`DTS -230584300921369, next:40000 st:0 invalid dropping`
`PTS -230584300921369, next:40000 invalid dropping st:0`.
This goes away if adding a line with `duration XXX` after each `file ...` line, where `XXX` is arbitrary and does not change the result. See [this SO post]/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952350/ffmpeg-concat-demuxer-with-duration-filter-issue) that points out to repeat the last frame.

Comment: That adding `duration XXXX` removes the `DTS -230584300921369` problem is confirmed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368105/ffmpeg-custom-sequence-input-images/51618079#51618079).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem ultimately was that trying different things lead to my overwriting of the source PNG images with each other, leading to what seemed like and apparent incorrect repetition of images in the movie.

For reference, a working command that puts the images in the correct order (not working directly with `-filter image2 -pattern_type glob -i "*.png"`) is:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel warning \
 -r:v 5 -f concat -safe 0 \
  -i <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' \
  -exec echo "file $(pwd)/"{} \; | sort -V \
   | sed 's/$/\nduration 1.0/' | tee list.txt) \
  -vf fps=30 -codec:v libx264 -preset veryslow \
  -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 28 \
  -an AMDG.mp4
```

where:

- `-y` overwrites the output file without asking;
- `-r:v 5` uses 5 input images per second;
- the `-maxdepth 1` part avoids finding files in subdirectories (adapt to taste);
- the `sed` part replaces (`s`) every line end and newline (`$`) with a newline (`\n`) followed by `duration 1.0` (the number seems arbitrary) after each `file XXXX` line in the implicit input file that `find` is building. This list is saved for debugging to `list.txt`; remove `| tee list.txt` not to do this;
- `safe 0` is actually safe and allows the file paths to contain `./` as returned by `find`.

If your input file names contain spaces, you will need to play around with the process redirection part.

Comment: For completeness, it would still be interesting to know whether there is a way of concatenating two streams generated with having `-pattern_type glob -i 'pattern1*.png' -pattern_type glob -i 'pattern2*.png'` into one; with `-map 0 -map 1` they are both included but as separate streams.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you had JPEGs, you could try:

```
find | grep jpg$ | sort -n -k 1.8 | xargs cat | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - output.mp4
```

which concatenates all the JPEG files into a big sorted stream.  This works for JPG, but might not work for PNG, which is not as streamable.

- The sort assumes all files are in the current directory, and sorts numerically by the 7th character. (Not 5th, because sort indexes from 1, and find will output the leading directory part: e.g., `./image123.jpg`.)  This is not very robust, but you get the idea.
- Use `find --print0`, `sort -z`, and `xargs -0` if there might be spaces in the filenames.